# Unable to connect Sequel Pro with mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, database, docker, sequelpro

I feel like this should be an easy fix but I can't seem to figure this out. I just installed docker and ran:

```
docker run -d --name test-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test mysql
```

I did this to create my first container. After that I opened sequel pro an typed in the correct things to connect to the database. I got this...

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
```

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

```
MySQL said: Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it matter that the 7 and 2 are transposed in the third code example? Additionally are you providing a port number to sequel pro?

Comment: I do not know, I noticed that too